# Function executes only once

Tags: jquery, function

I'm trying to change navbar color from white to blue and vice versa using toggle button.When i click on button it changes from white to blue but when i click another time it won't turn back to white color.

Here is my jQuery code.

```
$(".switch").click(function(){
    var numberOfClicks=0;
    numberOfClicks++;
    if(numberOfClicks%2 !=0){
    $("#nav-menu").css("background-color","blue");
    }else {
    $("#nav-menu").css("background-color","white");
    }

    });
```

And here is the code of toggle button

```
 <label  class="switch">
      <input  type="checkbox">
      <div class="slider" id="toggleButton"></div>
     </label>
```

Comment: You declare `numberOfClicks` each time the button is clicked - it'll never increment past 1

Comment: Move `numberOfClicks` to outside of `$(".switch").click(function(){` new variable is created again n again

Answer (score 0):

You declare `numberOfClicks` *inside* your click handler. That means that every time the button is clicked, the variable is instantiated to zero again. It will always be 1.

Instead, do something like this:

```
var numberOfClicks=0;

$(".switch").click(function(){
    numberOfClicks++;
    if(numberOfClicks%2 !=0){
    $("#nav-menu").css("background-color","blue");
    }else {
    $("#nav-menu").css("background-color","white");
    }

    });
```

Comment: Yes i totally overlooked it basically resets numberOfClicks to zero every time function is called.Therefore maximum value is 1.

Answer (score 0):

try my answer, you can toggle classes to change background color

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.blue{background-color:blue !important};
.white{background-color:white !important};
</style>

<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-preheader navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle white collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="./">Default</a></li>
              <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
              <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </div>
<script>
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function(){
$('.navbar-toggle').toggleClass('blue white');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works nice but somehow it won't work when i set classes blue and white in separate css file.

Comment: Dude it works fine even if, we declare those classes in separate css file too, i tried it, it works fine, try once

Answer (score 0):

1/3) - You can check if button is checked or not.
If checked, than blue, if not, then white:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".switch").click(function(){
  var nav_menu = $("#nav-menu");
 if( $(this).children("input").prop("checked") ) {
   nav_menu.addClass("blue");
 }
 else {
   nav_menu.removeClass("blue")
 }
  });
});
```

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label  class="switch">
<input  type="checkbox">
<div class="slider" id="toggleButton"></div>
</label>

<div id="nav-menu">nav-menu</div>
```

2/3) - Or you can ckeck if element has class `blue` or not:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".switch").click(function(){
    var nav_menu = $("#nav-menu");
    if( nav_menu.hasClass("blue") ) {
     nav_menu.removeClass("blue")
    }
    else {
     nav_menu.addClass("blue");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label  class="switch">
<input  type="checkbox">
<div class="slider" id="toggleButton"></div>
</label>

<div id="nav-menu">nav-menu</div>
```

3/3) - Or shortest way with class toggle:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".switch").click(function(){
    $("#nav-menu").toggleClass("blue");
  });
  
});
```

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label  class="switch">
<input  type="checkbox">
<div class="slider" id="toggleButton"></div>
</label>

<div id="nav-menu">nav-menu</div>
```

Comment: First one works perfectly.It really did the job.Hvala